# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration error in Facebook appliction

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trig to post a status using FB.api . But getting the error like "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration error in Facebook application". I have searched this in Google.I came to know that the redirect uri should be the same as website url of Facebook application. But in my code nowhere i am using the redirect uri. This is my code

```
   <html>
  <body>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
    appId      : 'ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : 'http://localhost/APP/chnel.php', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, 
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
   });

 // Additional initialization code here



    FB.login(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      });
        } else {
 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
         }
      });
     };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
       (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

So how i can fix this. i am developing the application in localhost only

Comment: You are getting this message while calling the Auth dialog? Have you set `http://localhost/` as _Website with Facebook Login_ in your app settings?

Comment: yes when i am calling FB.login that error occurs.And i have set http://localhost/ as Website with Facebook Login.Still getting the same error. am i wrong with redirect uri?. If so how to fix it in the above code.

Comment: any fix to this? having same issue... would be nice if facebook DISPLAYED what url was passed and what is needed (maybe if app is in sandbox mode)

Comment: Generally it's not the website with login setting that's the issue, instead, it's the application domain that's improperly set.  What have you set in the domain section of your app config (top area of settings section)?